# vb.net Combobox resets to un-selected on lost focus when bound to Objectdatasource

Tags: vb.net, combobox, lostfocus

Sorry I'm new to vb.net 2010. I'm also new to subclassing. The comobobox is used as a lookup.

I have a comboxbox that is bound to a bindingSource. The problem is after I select an item on my combobox and loses its focus it reverts to blank. Why is this? Weird.

```
 My tables:
  tblUsers
  -FullName
  -UserName
  -Password
  -UserTypeID

  tblUserType
  -UserTypeID
  -UserType (Admin, Supervisor, Encoder)

  My Class Library:
  -Users.vb = table encapsulation of tblUsers
  -UserDB.vb = methods for my tblUsers

  -UserType.vb = table encapsulation of tblUserType
  -UserTypeDB.vb = methods for my tblUserType

  Data Sources:
  -UserBindingSource = Users.vb Class
  -UserTypeBindingSource = UserType.vb Class


 Databindings for my UserTypeComboBox:

    UserTypeComboBox.DataSource = UserTypeBindingSource
    UserTypeComboBox.DisplayMember = UserType
    UserTypeComboBox.ValueMember = UserTypeID
    UserTypeComboBox.SelectedValue =  UsersBindingSource - UserTypeID    

My Code Below:

 Public Class frmUsers_AddEdit    

     Private newUser As Users 
     Private usertypeList As List(Of UserType)

     Private Sub LoadComboboxes()
         Try

             usertypeList = UserTypeDB.GetUserTypeList
             UserTypeComboBox.DataSource = usertypeList

         Catch ex As Exception
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType.ToString)
         End Try

     End Sub

     Private Sub frmUsers_AddEdit_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

         Me.LoadComboboxes()
         UsersBindingSource.Add(newUser)

     End Sub 

 end class
```

The frmUsers_AddEdit is the form I use to add/edit User data into the database. I'm still on the adding stage. No code yet for edit.

Combobox Issue: Everytime I select an Item from the UserTypeCombobox (ex. "Encoder") the selection will revert back to un-selected when it loses focus. :-(

Comment: Weird I tried the BindingSource.suspendBinding and BindingSource.ResumeBinding it seems to solve the problem. But after compiling the problem persists again. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it a Causes Validation value of False. If that doesnt work maybe your ComboBox DropDownStyle isnt set to DropDownList

add the following property to your combobox in the code ahead and try that

```
CausesValidation="false"
```

or try adding this in your code behind for the dropdownstyle

```
ComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
```

Comment: how do I that? sorry i'm new to vb.net.

Comment: I tried the causesvalidation = false. It does solves the lost focus blank text property of the combobox but it also has other effect. The result is no data is saved in the database. :-(

Comment: I tried simple, dropdown, dropdownlist the problem still presists. Combobox reverts back to empty string on lost focus. Grrrr....

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the problem. In my User.vb class I have a public property "UserType" and in my UserType.vb class I also have the same public property called "UserType". Would this cause a conflict?

I deleted both classes and started over. In my UserType.vb class I renamed the public property to Utype. After that I reconfigured the databindings  on my add/edit form. The combobox problem disappeared.

Was the duplicate public property name was the cause of the combobox lost focus problem? I'm still not sure if that was the real issue. But i'm glad my combobox is now working properly.

Comment: my mistake the problem still exists. The code that is causing the problem is UserBindingSource.Add(newUser) on form load. :-(